Is the summary of arguments rather convincing?
I have a philosophical theory about afterlife really existing. It is because thoughts are mathematical waves which remain existing.
I have another philosophical theory about climate change making it mandatory to change the life style using more the mind and less the body.

Hello Adib. PhilSE is a Q&A forum where questions should be well-sourced, clear factual questions. We don't allow what-do-you-think questions. Don't take closure personally, and when you get a chance, please read the site FAQ by clicking on the question mark in the upper-right corner.
